# Page breaks in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, sapui5

What is the best practice for creating specific page breaks in SAPUI5 and is it actually possible?

Classical CSS atributes `page-break-after` and `page-break-before`doesn't seem to work in my case. For example, I have two `sap.m.VBox` elements and I attached them a CSS class which specifies `page-break-after: always !important;`when printing, but nothing happens. If I add 
`* {overflow-x: visible !important; overflow-y: visible !important;}` then it will break and continue to draw the content in next page if it doesn't fit in one page, but it doesn't work in IE.

I have tryed also adding an empty `div` element that would work as a page break indicator, but still CSS wouldn't do anything. I guess that's because everything in SAPUI5 is put into one content div.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem adding `section {height: 100%;}` in `@media print`, but still it's quite unreliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding an empty element in between.

If you want a break that is 200 pixels high, your page content can look like this:

```
return new sap.m.Page({
content:[
oVBox1,
sap.m.Panel({height: "200px", width: "100%}),
oVBox2
]
});
```

ofcourse you might want to set your panel background-color to transparent ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I achieved somewhat automatic dividing with CSS, but it's unstable though. I have one flex box that contains N number of SVG charts, and I adjusted the margins between the SVG elements so that each chart would be correctly positioned in each page. Anyway I haven't found any "legit" and stable way how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The "page-break-after" is ignored because the property display of SAPUI5 views is set to inline-block.

Simply override the CSS style for the corresponding class with a custom CSS and it should work:
`.sapUiView {
   display: block;
}`