# Page Break in SAPUI5

Tags: css, sapui5, page-break

Trying to implement page break using `<p style="page-break-after:always" ></p>` and it's working in HTML but not SAPUI5. I have checked [multiple links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097484/page-breaks-in-sapui5) where they are saying to override sap standard classes but also it did not worked.

`.sapUiView {
   display: block;
}`

Any idea how to solve it?

other links
[Link 1](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3412895)

Comment: Whenever i feel i *have* to change a standard class, I add `!important`, because it's hard to target all of those nested class structures.

Comment: I did it but no luck. I can see in Chrome debugging this class has changed with `display:block!important;` still the print is showing in same page.